# VBA Data Parsing from txt to excel

Tags: string, excel, vba, parsing, notepad

Okay I'll try to explain this the best way possible
- I am parsing .txt files which get imported into excel 
- The .txt files which are parsed all have static fields (sometimes)
- In the future these fields could change and may not be static therefore the below code would parse pretty sloppy stuff

**Questions:**
1. Assuming in the future that these string values can change (ie "CUSTOMER NAME:" changes to DISTRIBUTOR NAME:)
a. Is there are way I can manipulate the data to where I only have to establish the name of the strings and skip having to establish the location of the strings within the text based on character length? (ie without using Mid(text, act + 6, 9))

2. If so, how would I go about doing this? Some lines within the text file have 1, 2 or three fields (ie SOME INDICATOR:,NO STATUS:,AUTO RENEW:.. has three field values, while the first line has one, and the second two. I am guessing one way to do this would be to establish the name of the strings so that every field between said string and the next string would be the string fields value ie:

   ```
   ACCOUNT OPEN:(string 1)    05/10/15(string 1 value)    ACT TYPE:(string 2) PREMIUM (string value 2)
   ```

In a nutshell I am trying to find a way that I can making this parser 'intelligent' so to speak. While its no big deal using the below method for the first part of a customers record, in reality each record has additional screens (mainframe). There are also additional screens pertaining to other things such as inventory, order numbers, etc.. So you could see how this could become a large and tedious undertaking. I don't mind spending a few months to map each field, it is just more work that I think is necessary, so any input would be greatly appreciated on how I can do this.

3. Also my below code does not work completely. It correctly imports the first record of text file but repeats that exact record for the remainder of rows in excel ( ie account: ABCDEF12 is repeated for 100 rows in excel rather than going down the list of records. Each new record starts 20 lines down from the previous). I am assuming that I have my loop structure wrong? Any thoughts? Any thoughts on how I can make the autofit portion of the below code more efficient? Currently it adds a lot more time to how long my code takes to parse, trim, clean and autofit, and ideas on how to shorten this?

   ```
   Dim myFile As String
   Dim text As String
   Dim textline As String
   Dim cstAct as integer
   Dim actOpe as integer
   Dim cusNam as integer
   Dim act as integer
   Dim reg as integer

   myFile = "put file patch to text file here"
   myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

   Do Until EOF(1)
   Line Input #1, textline
   text = text & textline
   Loop

   cusAct = InStr(text, "ACCOUNT ")
   actOpe = InStr(text, "ACCOUNT OPEN:")
   reg = InStr(text, "REGION:")
   cusNam = InStr(text, "CUSTOMER NAME:")

   For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("b2").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("name").Range("a" & i).Value = Mid(text, act + 6, 9)
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("name").Range("b" & i).Value = Mid(text, cstAct + 6, 9)
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("name").Range("c" & i).Value = Mid(text, actOpe + 13, 27)
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("name").Range("d" & i).Value = Mid(text, cusNam  + 20, 19)

   next i

   'here I format and autofit the cells                         
   For x = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("b2").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row
   Range("a" & x).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(trim(Range("a" & x)))
   Range("b" & x).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(trim(Range("b" & x)))
   Range("c" & x).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(trim(Range("c" & x)))
   'etc etc
   next x
   ```

'Text file which is parsed and then imported into excel

```
ACCOUNT ABCDEF12                                                                 
ACCOUNT OPEN:     05/10/15              ACT TYPE: PREMIUM          
CUSTOMER NAME:    JOHN B. SMITH         CSA REP:  154983                   
CUSTOMER ADDRESS: 123 SOMEWHERE DRIVE   SOMETHING HERE:                   
LAST ORDER:       06/24/2011             COUNTRY CODE: UNITED STATES      
INVOICE #:        123456789             STATE CODE:    CALIFORNIA         
LAST MAINTENANCE: 01/02/15               COUNTY CODE:  UNCODED            
SOME INDICATOR:   NO   COMPLAINTS: NO   IPM IND:       DATAPREP/PERF4     
SOME INDICATOR:   NO STATUS:  NONE      AUTO RENEW:    YES                
SOMETHING HERE:   NO                             
SOMETHING HERE:          ABC IND:       
SOMETHING HERE:   2    ABC ASSET NO:  T
```

.......REMAINDER OF TXT FILE REPEATS...JUST DIFFERENT RECORDS....

```
ACCOUNT ZXYFDG13                                                                 
ACCOUNT OPEN:     05/10/15              ACT TYPE: PREMIUM          
CUSTOMER NAME:    JANE B. SMITH         CSA REP:  154983                   
CUSTOMER ADDRESS: 123 SOMEWHERE DRIVE   SOMETHING HERE:                   
LAST ORDER:       06/24/2011             COUNTRY CODE: UNITED STATES      
INVOICE #:        123456789             STATE CODE:    CALIFORNIA         
LAST MAINTENANCE: 01/02/15               COUNTY CODE:  UNCODED            
SOME INDICATOR:   NO   COMPLAINTS: NO   IPM IND:       DATAPREP/PERF4     
SOME INDICATOR:   NO STATUS:  NONE      AUTO RENEW:    YES                
SOMETHING HERE:   NO                             
SOMETHING HERE:          ABC IND:  NO     
SOMETHING HERE:   2    REGION:  NE
```

.....Records continue Indefinitely.........

Comment: Could you be so kind and provide an exact form of your data? It looks like the length of each record's property is the same. You can use pastebin.com service...

Comment: sorry, my complete comment is below

Comment: I guess a better way to sum up the above question is this; The above code parses based on the location of a "Parent-String", ie "Account Number" and "Customer Name" within a text file. These Parent Strings repeat throughout the file and remain statiic. Using the Mid( function I obtain non-static strings based on the location of the parent strings (ie Account Number is static, but its substring isn't. So Account Number: ABCDEF12 becomes Account Number: ZXYFDG13 when the next iteration occurs. The issue I am having though is that with each iteration ABCDEF12 repeats over & over again.

Comment: I am thinking that one solution would be do change " Do Until EOF(1) to something else, so it stops at the next occurence of "Account Number" and restarts the loop? Perhaps I need to somehow reset the values of the Parent/Sub-Strings at the end of each For..Next Loop? Any help is greatly appreciated. In the meantime I will work on getting something uploaded to pastebin